# Wrong value using select from csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv, odbc

I have a csv file that store some rows like:

```
code      --name    --req   --country
VS161A0166--ÁO KHOÁC--S79095--VIETNAM
VS161A0240--ÁO THUN --S79096--VIETNAM
```

Im using Odbc to connect and retreive data in c#

```
string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=c:;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False;HDR=NO;IMEX=1";
string sql_select;
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn;

conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
conn.Open();
sql_select = "select *  from [test.csv]";

obj_oledb_da = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql_select, conn);
obj_oledb_da.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();
```

But i get unexpected value

```
VS161A0166--ÁO KHOÁC--79095.000--VIETNAM
VS161A0240--ÁO THUN --79096.000--VIETNAM
```

How can i fix it? Thanks for help

Comment: What is the data type of the "req" column?

Comment: That is csv file bro, just text

Comment: Obviously the data adapter interpret it as a number. So there must be some sort of schema?

Comment: Is there a *schema.ini* file in the same directory as your *test.csv* file?

Comment: i have no schema.ini file bro

Answer (score 0):

So, this will seem odd, but here's a solution in C# that will reference the VisualBasic namespace. I know, odd.

```
using  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

public List<MyVal> GetValues() {
    var path = "path/to/file";
    var list = new List<MyVal>();
    using(var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(path)) {
        csvReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
        csvReader.SetDelimiters("--");
        while(!csvReader.EndOfData) {
            var currentRow = csvReader.ReadField();
            if(csvReader.LineNumber != 1)
                list.Add(new MyPoco() { Code = currentRow[0], Name = currentRow[1], Req = currentRow[2], Country = currentRow[3]});
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Using this as the class MyPoco:

```
public class MyPoco {
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Req {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
}
```